# Multiple text field, show/hide based on radio selection (Html,JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I am working on a `form` right now and have the following problem.

**Problem**

I have multiple questions on the same page with the exact same answer options (yes/no/maybe), and one of them is "maybe". After the user has checked a `radio-button` or a `check-box` called "maybe" a `text field` should appear. I have implemented a javascript but it doesn't seem to work. I don't really know how to program this when there are multiple text fields and radio buttons.

I am fairly new to HTML/Jquery/Javascript/CSS.

How can this be achieved? I know similar questions have been asked, but I am really clueless at this point.

Thank you very much for your support!

[EDIT] I tried giving the  the same id's but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a fiddle with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/03gkgfah/1/

This is an anonymized excerpt from the form (i didn't simply it on purpose so you could have a better overview):

```
   <fieldset data-mini="false" data-inline="true">
<legend>1. Test question 1</legend>
  <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage01" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio01" value="yes" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio01">Yes</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage01" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio02" value="no" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio02">No</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage01" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio03" value="maybe" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio03">Maybe:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b" id="maybe_on">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage01" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_textinput01" value="" type="text" maxlength="150" placeholder="maybe...">
   </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>


   <fieldset data-mini="false" data-inline="true">
<legend>2. Test question 2?</legend>
  <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage02" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio01" value="yes" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio01">Yes</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage02" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio02" value="no" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio02">No</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage02" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio03" value="maybe" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_radio03">Maybe:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b" id="maybe_on">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage02" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q02_textinput01" value="" type="text" maxlength="150" placeholder="maybe...">
   </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset data-mini="false" data-inline="true">
<legend>2. Test question 3?</legend>
  <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage03" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio01" value="yes" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio01">Yes</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage03" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio02" value="no" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio02">No</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage03" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio03" value="maybe" type="radio">
    <label for="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_radio03">Maybe:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b" id="maybe_on">
    <input name="Teil01_Frage03" id="tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q03_textinput01" value="" type="text" maxlength="150" placeholder="maybe...">
   </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The .css:

```
#sonstiges_on{display:none;}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#maybe_on").hide();
$("input:radio[name*='Teil']").change(function(){//*=   to search for a substring
                                                //='Teil' because the name of the buttons begin with Teil
                                                //for example Teil01_Frage01
        if(this.value == 'maybe' && this.checked){
          $("#maybe_on").show();
        }else{
          $("#maybe_on").hide();
        }
}); });
```

Comment: _id_ should be unique, you used "maybe_on" on all of them, also `$("input:radio[name="Teil01_Frage01")` Use single quote for one of the double quote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, IDs must be unique, and your maybe radio buttons share the same one. That aside, you could use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".maybe_on").hide();
    $("input:radio[name^='Teil01_']").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('.ui-grid-b.ui-responsive').find('.maybe_on').toggle((this.value == 'maybe' && this.checked));
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/03gkgfah/9/)**

Comment: thank you very much for your effort and time :) problem solved. Just one last question... I also have a checkbox "maybe" but sadly it doesn't work. On the other hand all radio-buttons "maybe" work perfectly with the above code. Do you have a suggestion on how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: nevermind, I just added another javacode where I replaced "radio" with "checkbox" and seemed to work perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Created an inpage Javascript function that checks if the input field in question is clicked. And if it is, it shows the 'maybe' input.

```
function yesnoCheck() {
if (document.getElementById('tUmfrage01_p01_f01_q01_radio03').checked) {
    document.getElementById('maybe_on').style.display = 'block';
}
else document.getElementById('maybe_on').style.display = 'none';

}
```

**edit**
http://jsfiddle.net/sanova/03gkgfah/15/

Comment: What happens when you click maybe on the second and third questions?

Comment: I didn't code those, I've just updated the JS and edited my answer to include them @j08691

Comment: That sort of works, but if you select maybe, and then change the answer to yes or no, the maybe stays open.